# Pre-fetching queries in apollo-client react

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

This is a [snippet](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/prefetching.html) from the official Apollo Docs that help prefetching. However, my concern is that I am not using a functional component but a class component and I am not able to see 'client' in the props of the class.

```
const FeedEntry = ({ entry, currentUser, onVote, client }) => {
  const repoLink = `/${entry.repository.full_name}`;
  const prefetchComments = (repoFullName) => () => {
    client.query({
      query: COMMENT_QUERY,
      variables: { repoName: repoFullName },
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="media">
      ...
      <div className="media-body">
        <RepoInfo
          description={entry.repository.description}
          stargazers_count={entry.repository.stargazers_count}
          open_issues_count={entry.repository.open_issues_count}
          created_at={entry.createdAt}
          user_url={entry.postedBy.html_url}
          username={entry.postedBy.login}
        >
          <Link to={repoLink} onMouseOver={prefetchComments(entry.repository.full_name)}>
              View comments ({entry.commentCount})
          </Link>
        </RepoInfo>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const FeedEntryWithApollo = withApollo(FeedEntry);
```

I am also using Graphql. Here is what my code looks like for two components which require data:

**BAR GRAPH**

```
    class BarGraphData extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
            data: {}
            }
        }
       componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            data: nextProps.data ? nextProps.data : {}
        });
       }
      render(){ 
        return (<BarGraph data={this.state.data} />) 
      }
    }

export default graphql(BAR_GRAPH_QUERY, {
options: ({ year, month, name  }) => ({
    variables: { year, month, name }
})
 })(BarGraphData);
```

**Line chart:**

```
    class LineGraphData extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
            data: {}
            }
        }
       componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            data: nextProps.data ? nextProps.data : {}
        });
    }
       render(){ 
        return (<LineGraph data={this.state.data} />) 
        }
    }

   export default graphql(LINE_GRAPH_QUERY, {
   options: ({ year, month, name  }) => ({
    variables: { year, month, name }
   })
   })(LineGraphData);
```

I want to prefetch data for the line chart on hovering the bargraph (as click an item on bargraph should show its line chart ). However I am not able to access 'client' although I have defined the apollo client higher up in my tree and without prefetching this works - but it is slow.

Answer (score 0):

To get the client into the props of your component use the `withApollo` higher order component as done in the last line if the example in the Apollo Documentation:

```
const FeedEntryWithApollo = withApollo(FeedEntry);
```

In your example:

```
export default withApollo(
  graphql(BAR_GRAPH_QUERY, {
    options: ({ year, month, name  }) => ({
      variables: { year, month, name }
    })
  })(LineGraphData)
);
```

The higher order component is exported just like the `graphql` higher order component from `react-apollo`.